# Is it possible to call from C# a C++ function that has parameter of type Dataset

Tags: c#, c++, managed-c++

We have a legacy C++ program (standard C++ not managed) with many methods.  Most use parameters of char and int.   However, one has the following method signature:

```
Convert(CDataSet &DataSet, CValue &Var, char *pOutput, int &nParser)
```

We need to call that method from C#.  We have an existing Managed C++ class that can call the unmanaged methods that need char and int without problems.  But we are at wits end on how to call a C++ method from C# when it needs to have a dataset passed to it.  Some have told us that is impossible to do so.  Is that true?

If we can't pass a dataset is it possible to pass an object and then have managed class cast it as dataset to pass to unmanaged class?

Comment: Since all your parameters are pointers, calling the method is no problem. The problem is from where to get an instance of `DataSet` or how to manipulate it.

Comment: You could also look into cxxi and swig. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748156/call-c-exported-function-in-c-sharp

Comment: You cannot call C++ methods from C# at all, unless the object is COM compliant.  Are you talking about free functions?

Comment: Using C++/CLI as the bridge/glue layer between C# and C++ is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your managed C++ wrapper lib accept System.Data.DataSet for example and convert it's data to CDataSet and call unmanaged code. On return convert the updates back (if needed).

UPD: by "convert" I mean create a new instance of CDataSet class inside your wrapper method, populate it's data from managed object and then call unmanaged function. When it returns transfer data back to original managed object if necessary and return.

If you need to manage the updates to the object between calls or accross process boundaries (i.e. other function calls result in updates to this object even when object is not passed) than create a wrapper around unmanaged object and provide managed interface that would let you manipulate the object at required level.

Comment: That was my thinking but how do u convert it to a CDataSet?

Comment: what are these CDataSet and CValue types BTW?

Comment: Unfortunately CDataSet is a custom container class that holds a set of data.  It was written in 1999.  Basically it was built to mimic a Dataset before they we widely available.  It takes SQL statements and reads from the DB into a highly customized array

Comment: correction it is not an array.  It is a linked list of pointers with 'rows' that have 'columns' and each column in a row can be of different datatype